# Altium Layer Stackup for Aluminium (IMS) PCB

Tags: pcb, altium, aluminium

I am needed to do a single layer PCB in Altium. I have no routing on the bottom layer but in the layer stack manager, I am not able to remove the bottom layer copper. Also, I can't choose or find any aluminium core.

This is my current stackup:
[image]

For aluminium based, is that bottom layer copper there with no connection naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For aluminium based, is that bottom layer copper there with no connection naturally?

You don't have to make anything on the bottom layer, even if it's there and non-removable.

All you need to do is to generate the necessary gerbers *(top layer i.e. copper, mask, paste, and silkscreen, and also the drills and board extents)*, define the PCB properties (thickness, type & material, copper weight, colours, tolerances etc) in a document, pack everything together and send to the manufacturer.

Comment: Ok got it. I will do that. If the PCB thickness that i want is lets say 1.6mm, does that include the aluminium plate below it? or its just the pcb itself

Comment: @mdabdillah For FR4 PCBs it's usually the bare board's thickness so the finished thickness becomes slightly higher than 1.6mm unless you specify the final thickness to be 1.6mm. For aluminium, it depends on your requirements and the PCB manufacturer's capabilities. You may want the finished thickness to be 1.6mm but they may suggest/offer you a closer size depending on their stock and capabilities. There are some standard aluminium bare thicknesses so the best answer could come from your PCB manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks alot for the information!